# Chi squared test in R for Deviance between 2 models

Tags: r

I found the total change in deviance between 2 models to be 6.33 with 6 degrees of freedom.

How can I do a chisquared test to test the goodness of fit?

I tried `dchisq(6,6.33)` which gives me 0.11. Does it mean I can reject at 90%?

But when I look the chi-squared with 6 degrees of freedom, the 90% confidence interval is at 10.64, which is sure rejection. (I can also reject at 75% - 7.84, which contradicts the above which suggests rejecting at 89%)

Comment: Error in dchisq(6, 6.33, lower.tail = FALSE) : unused argument (lower.tail = FALSE). I'm assuming the R already assumes it's false, and we only need to use it if its true

Comment: I got 0.46, does it mean I can reject in the 54-99% region

Comment: I'm using glms, and anova is not appropriate for them, which is why I'm using deviance. So getting 0.46 means that I can't reject the Null Hypothisis at the 0-46% level? In which case we can reject the 50%, but the chi-sq value at 0.5 is 5.3

Comment: and this conversation is not an r conversation, this is a stats conversation meant for another stack...you will get more complete answers there...

Comment: @ZheyuanLi I was looking at this question again, and I got confused with the p chisq value definition. If it's 1 -> we reject the null hypothesis, hence we want small values of pchisq. Does it mean we reject null hypotheses at (1-pchisq) level? Is this significance probability? (As mentioned by bethany I should ask on stats, but I though you could provide me with a quick answer)